# @Component scan for spring bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have an interface named Coach that implement by TennisCoach and i am trying to scan the beans in xml

with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />` but when i am runing my main method i have this error

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\pooya\eclipse-workspace\spring-demo-ann\bin\com\luv2code\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\pooya\eclipse-workspace\spring-demo-ann\bin\com\luv2code\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:275)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:90)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1366)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:393)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:518)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
 at com.luv2code.springdemo.helloappann.main(helloappann.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\pooya\eclipse-workspace\spring-demo-ann\bin\com\luv2code\springdemo\Coach.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57)
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:430)
 ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:184)
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:152)
 at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:273)
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
 ... 28 more
```

```html
package com.luv2code.springdemo;


public interface Coach {

 public String getDailyWorkout();
 
}
```

```html
package com.luv2code.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component("thatSillyCoach")
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

 
 @Override
 public String getDailyWorkout() {
  return "Practice your backhand volley";
 }

}
```

```html
package com.luv2code.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class helloappann {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // read spring config file
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app.xml");
  
  // get the bean from spring container
  Coach theCoach = context.getBean("thatSillyCoach", Coach.class);
  
  // call a method on the bean
  System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    
  // close the context
  context.close();
  
 }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <!-- add entry to enable component scanning -->

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

</beans>
```

Comment: `Unsupported class file major version 57` means you have code that was compiled for Java 13, but you're running on a version of Java earlier than that. Options: 1) Change the Java used to run the code to Java 13. 2) Recompile the code to match the version of Java running the code (if it's your code causing the problem). 3) Get a different version of a library to a version that is compatible with the version of java running the code (if it's caused by a library).

Comment: thank you. I fix it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch in java versions: version 57 is java 13

You probably need to `mvn clean install` again and check your versions.

You can have a look there: https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion